# Prove inequality of measure in boolean algebra

Tags: measure-theory, boolean-algebra

If $\mu: B \rightarrow [0,1]$ is a measure on a boolean algebra $\mathcal{B}$, What is the best way to prove that $\mu(b \vee c) \leq \mu(b) + \mu(c)$? If $b \wedge c = 0$, this is an equality. What about when $b \wedge c > 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using this [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_algebra) of measure on a Boolean Algebra.

Notice that, in a Boolean Algebra, 
\begin{equation}
x < y \;\Longrightarrow \; x \wedge (x' \wedge y) = 0 \text{ and } x \vee (x' \wedge y) = y.\tag{$*$}
\end{equation}

Let us see that $\mu$ is order-preserving.
If $x \leq y$, then $$\mu(y) = \mu(x \vee y) = \mu(x \vee (x' \wedge y)) =_{\because (*)} \mu(x) + \mu(x' \wedge y) \geq \mu(x),$$
where the inequality follows from $\mu(x' \wedge y) \geq 0$.

Now, $$\mu(b \vee c) = \mu(b \vee (b' \wedge c)) =_{\because (*)} \mu(b) + \mu(b' \wedge c) \leq \mu(b) + \mu(c),$$
where the inequality follows from the $b'\wedge c \leq c$.

Comment: The step I'm missing is how do you get $x \leq y \Leftrightarrow x = x \wedge y \textrm{ (by def) } \Leftrightarrow y = x \vee y$? (I wonder about the second equivalence).

Comment: In your question, you make use of the binary operations, $\wedge$ and $\vee$ and also of the order relation. So I suppose you know about the connection between these. The operations may be defined in terms of the order relation by $x \wedge y = \inf\{x,y\}$ and $x \vee y = \sup\{x,y\}$. So, if $x \leq y$, then what are $x \wedge y$ and $x \vee y$.

Comment: Conversely, $x \wedge y \leq x$ and $x \leq x \vee y$, so if $x = x \wedge y$, then $x \leq y$, yielding $x \vee y = y$.

Comment: If that isn't enough, and since you seem to understand the first equivalence, I suppose [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211132/show-that-x-wedge-y-x-iff-x-vee-y-y-using-the-following-properties) can help you.